# Jess substring manipulation

Tags: pattern-matching, rules, jess

I use jess rule engine and i would like to achieve substring matching.
Specifically, i have a  deftemplate person and i check person slot values in left hand of a rule e.g.

`(defrule vsvmntud (declare (salience 1)) (person  (job unemployed)) =>....`

Above code will match job with entire string "unemployed". I would like to match substrings,for example if job contains substring "em".
Is this possible;

Comment: Is there any site / Videos /link which has Jess (Java Rule Engine) sample program from basics to complex and very complex?

Answer (score 1):

Since Jess 7, there is direct support for regular expressions: a rule like

```
(defrule vsvmntud
  (person (job /.*em.*/))
   =>
  ...
```

would match the `job` slot against the Java regular expression `.*em.*` .

You can also use any of the functions in the Jess library -- for example

```
(defrule vsvmntud
  (person (job ?j&:(str-index em ?j)))
   =>
  ...
```

does the same thing (the function `str-index` returns `FALSE` if no match is found, or a number -- which is interpreted as `TRUE` when converted to boolean -- otherwise.)

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Hill.My honor to have an answer from you.